# Am I over using <ul> for layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to create a small web widget, you can see it at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/ta8YR/1/). Right now it is organized by placing lists within lists and content within those lists. All of this is supposed to sit, as a bar, fixed to the bottom of your window, over the current website. I want to know, is my list set up too cumbersome, and at the same time there a better(more efficient) way to use CSS to create this same layout?

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="app_container_T t_ul">
    <li>
        <ul class="menu_T t_ul">
            <li>
                <button class="large_menu_button_T">+</button>
                <button class="large_menu_button_T">T</button>
                <button class="small_menu_button_T options">o</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="container_element_T t_ul resizableui-widget-content" id="1">
            <li class="content_header_T">
                <button class="t_intect_button close_button_T">-</button>
                <form name="search_form" class="search_form_T">
                    <input type="text" name="search_input" class="search_bar_T"></input>
                    <button class="search_button_T" name="search_button" onclick="add_timeline_element"></button>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="content_container_T">
                <button value="Timeline" id="1" class="content_selection_button_T">Timeline</button>
                <button value="Relevent" id="1" class="content_selection_button_T">Relevent</button>
                <button value="Mentions" id="1" class="content_selection_button_T">Mentions</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="container_T">
        <button class="t_intect_button close_button_T">-</button>
        <textarea class="text_area_T" warp="hard" placeholder="place holder"></textarea>
        <button value="Add Photo" class="composition_button_T photo_button_T"></button>
        <button value="Add Location" class="composition_button_T location_button_T"></button>
        <textarea class="word_count_T"></textarea>
        <button value="Undo: Off" class="composition_button_T Undo_button_T"></button>
        <button value="Submit" class="composition_button_T send_button_T"></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /*----Bar---*/
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  .app_container_T {
      position:fixed;
      bottom: 0px;
      left:0px;
      z-index: 998;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 150px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .app_container_T > li {
      /*create a class for them to share itll be faster, like t_ul*/
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .t_ul {
      list-style: none;
  }
  .app_container_T * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius:5px;
      vertical-align: text-bottom;
  }
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /*----Menu---*/
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  .menu_buffer {
      width: 60px;
  }
  .menu_T {
      background-color:lightblue;
      padding: 0px;
      width:60px;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .large_menu_button_T {
      background: #0016f0;
      color: #ffffff;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      margin: 3px;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius:10px;
  }
  .small_menu_button_T {
      background: #002aa9;
      color: #ffffff;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      margin: 1px;
      font-size: 12px;
  }
  .options {
      margin-left: 26px;
  }
  /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /*Selection Element*/
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  .container_element_T {
      background-color:red;
      padding: 5px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 325px;
  }
  .content_header_T {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 35px;
  }
  .content_header_T > * {
      position: relative;
  }
  .close_button_T {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      vertical-align: top
  }
  .search_form_T {
      width: 90%;
      height: 35px;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  .content_title_T {
      width: 90%;
      height: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  .content_container_T {
      overflow: scroll;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .content_selection_button_T {
      font-size: 100%;
      width:100%;
      height: 25%;
  }
  .content_list_T {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 2px;
      background: #0c5bd4;
      overflow: auto;
  }
  .t_content {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      background: #40aeee;
      border: 1px solid #fffeda;
  }
  .t_content_container_image {
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
  }
  .t_content_container_text {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-left: 2px;
      height: 100%;
      width: initial;
  }
  /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /*Timeline Element*/
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  .search_bar_T {
      background-color:white;
      box-shadow: rgb(204, 204, 204) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;
      border: 1px solid rgb(178, 210, 203);
      border-radius: 8px;
      font-size: 12px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 87%;
  }
  .search_button_T {
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 1px;
      background-color: #d4d4d4;
      font-family:'EntypoRegular';
      color: #5f615c;
      font-size: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
  }
  /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /*Alt Element*/
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  .container_T {
      background-color:red;
      padding: 5px;
      height: 150px;
      width: 325px;
  }
  .text_area_T {
      height: 80%;
      width: 90%;
  }
  .composition_button_T {
      margin: 0px 2px;
      height: 20%;
      width: 10%;
  }
  .word_count_T {
      height: 20%;
      width: 10%;
      background: transparent;
      color: #b1b7b6;
      margin: 0px 15%;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

[Here's how HTML5Doctor describes `<ul>` and `<li>`](http://html5doctor.com/):

> ### ul
>
> The ul element represents a list of items, where the order of the
>   items is not important — that is, where changing the order would not
>   materially change the meaning of the list.
>
> ### li
>
> The li element represents a list item. If its parent element is an ol,
>   ul, or menu element, then the element is an item of the parent
>   element's list, as defined for those elements. Otherwise, the list
>   item has no defined list-related relationship to any other li element.

Here's how I describe it:

> **If it ain't a list, don't use a list**

If the layout has no semantic meaning, and the elements are just used for layouting, you should consider `<div>` instead.

Comment: div is a fairly general tag, and would require a bit of css magic to make it work with jquery's resize. Is there any more specific element instead of div?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled Elements fall under 2 categories. There are *block elements* like `<div>` and `<p>`, and *inline elements* like `<a>` and `<span>`. Aside from functional differences, the names merely provide semantic meaning and nothing more. Sectioning and grouping elements generally fall under block elements.